# What is the purpose of publishing to npm using a scoped package?

Tags: angular, npm

I see some modules and packages publishing to npm using a [scoped package](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/scoped-packages) if your project is a public project: e.g. @angular

Are there advantages to publishing to a scoped package? What's the purpose of publishing to a scoped package?

Answer (score 3):

According to [the NPM blog](http://blog.npmjs.org/post/116936804365/solving-npms-hard-problem-naming-packages):

> With 141,898 modules on npm, it has been getting hard to find a name that isn’t 
>   taken.
>
> Scopes are like namespaces for npm packages
>   This means that you don’t have to worry about someone else taking your package 
>   name. Only you can add packages in your scope.

Also, see (just discovered this):

[Understanding npm package @-prefix: @angular/router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/understanding-npm-package-prefix-angular-router)