# Content Delivery Network unpkg.com @angular path syntax

Tags: angular, cdn, unpkg

In an Angular2 demo, there is a script src that uses the [unpkg.com CDN](https://unpkg.com).

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js"></script>
```

I am trying understand what the `@angular` path does and how it works.
I have tried looking at the documentation but have not found an explaination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The angular team prefixes all of their package names with @ just to call them out as being official packages. There's no special syntax at work here, just naming convention.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. In fact the package name is `@angular/core` which explains why `https://unpkg.com/@angular/` didn't get me any version choices but https://unpkg.com/@angular/core/ does.