# What is cnpm? How to use it?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have recently come across a project that extensively uses cnpm for package managing. I saw something like 
var a = require(@renil/a);

I have never seen something like this(@) in node when requiring a module.
Can anybody help me out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding npm package @-prefix: @angular/router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/understanding-npm-package-prefix-angular-router)

Answer (score 6):

Those are actually two unrelated things.  cnpm I had not heard of until I saw your question.  After googling, it appears to be a Chinese maintained registry of node modules.  Not sure what else is different but I'd probably stay away from it unless you know you need it.

The @ symbol in a package name has to do with scoping related modules.  That's well covered in the npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Comment: Its a big project . client is from china.. a lot of packages are defined using this package manager. I was thinking to remove them from private repo and make it local. Do you think its a nice idea.?

Comment: Yes, and I also would run them through snyk.io to see if there are known exploits against them.

Comment: It appears to be focused on having a company managed package repository. And yes, it appears to be mostly developed in and for China. It not too good at explaining itself. EG I can't find a man page nor reference to the flags.

Answer (score 3):

These are [scoped npm packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope):

> All npm packages have a name. Some package names also have a scope. A scope follows the usual rules for package names (url-safe characters, no leading dots or underscores). When used in package names, preceded by an @-symbol and followed by a slash, e.g.
>
> ```
> @somescope/somepackagename
> ```
>
> Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together, and also affect a few things about the way npm treats the package.