# Ionic2 - What's the meaning of the At symbol @ on import directives?

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm a novice on this world of `Ionic2` / `Cordova`.

I noticed that some imports have the `At: @` symbol in the import directives and others don't have it. For example:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

I searched a lot on Google what's the meaning of this symbol and what happens if I use it or not but didn't find a clear answer about this.

Then I have this question:

> What's the meaning of the `At: @` symbol on import directives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding npm package @-prefix: @angular/router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/understanding-npm-package-prefix-angular-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's literally just a part of a filename.

NPM supports ["scoped" packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope). A scope name always starts with an @. So things from the `@angular` scope are in the `@angular/` directory.