# Can't find the proper configuration for .babel and react-hot-loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, babeljs, react-hot-loader

I'm using babel 7.

In their docs they mention the new naming for plugin is with `@babel/` prefix.

React-hot-loader babrlrc config recommendation is:

```
{
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

my .babelrc config is:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/env", "@babel/react"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["@babel/react-hot-loader"]
    },
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Is it correct to assume that `@babel/react-hot-loader` is correct definision?

I could not find any more docs about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying `@babel/react-hot-loader` will have `babel` look within itself for a plugin called `react-hot-loader`. From what I can tell the package/plugin you're trying to use is not maintained/owned by `babel` itself. Therefore `@babel/react-hot-loader` will not work. You should configure your `.babelrc` as per the documentation of the plugin you're trying to use.

I think this is the plugin you're referring to in your question: [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/)

Follow these setup instructions: [react-hot-loader/getting-started](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/README.md#getting-started)

Comment: I see now. @babel is for Babel related plugin only. Thanks

Comment: @shmotam The **@** in the package name is used for namespacing. See this question on scoped packages: [Stack Overflow: @ prefix question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages). This is also documented in the NPM docs: [NPM docs: Scoped packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope)

Answer (score 1):

you have to still use it as mentioned in react hot reloader docs. below is the link

https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader#user-content-add-babel-before-typescript

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, react-hot-loader does not update there docs for prefix definition and I also found there given example 
https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/blob/master/examples/typescript/.babelrc

Using babel 7 prefix for other plugins but for react-hot-loader still the same

`{
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx",
    "react-hot-loader/babel"
  ]
}`