# What is the @ symbol meaning in require?

Tags: node.js

Recently I've seen many `require('@XXX')`, like

```
const PubSub = require(`@google-cloud/pubsub`);
```

what is this `@` meaning? where can I find the syntax?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NPM allows users to organize packages into organization scopes.

The `@google-cloud` part is the scope and `pubsub` is the package name.

[Organizing Packages docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-org-scopes-and-packages) explain it much better.

Comment: new link https://docs.npmjs.com/about-org-scopes-and-packages

Answer (score 0):

it is used for maintaining package belong to a specific organization, which help them to
Organizing People and Package Access and provide team permission (read/write) to package