# What is the difference between babel-preset-env and @babel/preset-env

Tags: babeljs

I have a hard time of understanding the difference between the two. Can someone explain why `@babel/preset-env` is more beneficial regarding to its `targets`?

Answer (score 4):

All packages prefixed with @ are part of the Babel 7 family. A few years ago, npm released their [scoped packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages) feature that enables organisations to publish multiple libraries that all start with `@insert_name_here`, have a slash (`/`) in between and end with the library's name. Just like:

```
@babel/preset-env
```

Also, when they transitioned from version 6 to 7, they started to use a [monorepo](https://gomonorepo.org), which made it much easier to use the scoped packages feature.