# What is the meaning of "@" prefix used in certain typescript libs

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-module

Examples of @ prefix:

- @angular/core
- @angular/material
- @ngrx/store
- @ngxs/store

Where as some libs don't.
Eg:

- rxjs

Is it random or does it mean anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the “at” (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Comment: Yes. The `@` indicates a `scoped package`. See the above linked topic for more information.