# @ sign in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I haven't touched JS in a while and see that there is a lot of use of the @ sign in node.js servers.

E.G.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
```

What do the @ signs mean? or if its for formatting, why is it set as that?

Comment: Duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Comment: From javascript point of view, It's just a name convenient.

Comment: Hey, the links above answer everything. thank you!