# What is the difference between @react-navigation/native and react-navigation

Tags: react-native

So, what is the difference between those two imports when using it in our React-Native projects?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have seen npm package names which follow this format - `@org-name/project-name`. These are called scoped packages. You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages) to know more about scoped packages.

Until v4.x, the react-navigation team used unscoped packages. (Refer [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/getting-started))

Starting from v5.x, the react-navigation team have started using scoped packages and hence the package name format - `@react-navigation/native`