# What does @dependency mean in npm?

Tags: npm, package.json

What does it mean when an npm dependency has an @sign? For example:

`npm install @reduxjs/toolkit` vs `npm install redux`

Comment: It's essentially a namespace owned by reduxjs in this case.  Only that npm user can create a package with that "@reduxjs" prefix.

Comment: It's a scoped package: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scope

Comment: Thanks, why is my question downvoted?

Comment: Wasn't me, but probably because the answer can be found already, eg. I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages

Comment: Wasn't me either. It is true that this question can be found in another post. But I wouldn't be so harsh as to downvote it, since it can be hard to find it. Specially if you don't know it is related to keywords like scope or namespace. Probably some years ago, but nowadays SO is filled with duplicates of duplicates with little variation that go unnoticed.