# How to use "@" in PowerShell with npm

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, electron

I tried to install `@electron-forge/cli` in the powershell with npm (`npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli`) following the [electron quick start tutorial](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start#package-and-distribute-your-application)

But whenever I try to run that, it just says `Unknown token in sourcecode` [...] `npm install --save-dev <<< @electron-forge/cli`

What am I missing?

I've already looked it up: No, I cant omit the @ ([What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages))

Other commands with an @ like `npx create-electron-app@latest my-app` *do* work

Comment: I just tried ```npm install --save-dev @electron-forge/cli``` in a new empty directory in a Command Prompt, a Windows PowerShell console and a PowerShell Core console and they all worked fine with npm version 6.14.6 and node version 14.6.0. Have you tried installing other packages with / without a leading ```@``` just to check they work? It *might* be a problem with your app (e.g. a corrupt package.json, or something..._)

Comment: I found out I can also just use quotes and it works just fine Thanks for your effort anyway!