# What is the '@' symbol for, when installing certain NPM packages?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

For certain packages I see you install with the '@' symbol, yet for others without it.
For example to install the Material UI React package.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWcmK.png

Yet to install tachyons, you only need 'npm install tachyons'. Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much.