# What does the @ mean in `import from '@/some/path'`

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js, typescript-module-resolution

Using IntelliJ IDEA to write a webapp in TypeScript, it autocomplete imports from other files of my project like this:

```
import {Symbol} from '@/components/Symbol';
```

What is the meaning of the `@` here? Where is it documented?

Note that this is when importing files from the same project. Imports from npm packages only use the package name (which may start with a @).

I haven’t found anything about this in [TypeScript Module Resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html), and when searching for `typescript @ import` in Google or SO, it seems the `@` character from the query is ignored...

Edit: This is in a Next.js project created with `npx create-next-app`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Comment: Are you using vite or webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turned out to be a [tsconfig path](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths), which was put there by `npx create-next-app`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vite or webpack, then your configuration will have a `resolve.alias` key to alias strings to a path.
[Vite documentation](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias)
[Webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvealias)