# What does this line mean in JS: "const { time } = require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");"

Tags: javascript, hardhat

Could anyone explain what these lines of code mean?

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const hre = require("hardhat");
const { time } = require(" @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");
```

In this line - `const { time } = require(" @nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers");`

We assign the path to the folder (hardhat-network-helpers) to the time variable? And what does this sign @ mean and where can I read about this sign?

thank in advance!

Comment: The `require()` is a **module import** command, loading the indicated module and then unpacking its contents. The module exports, presumably, a symbol "time" and that's what's desired in the importing context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages does this answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This answer assumes you are using NodeJS and commonjs and do not overwrite the `require` function

`require()` (https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) is commonjs module import command it returns a value of `module.exports` which you assign in module here package `@nomicfoundation/ hardhat-network-helpers` returns an object and `const { time } = ...` means assign `const time = require(...).time` here is the JavaScript syntax reference here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

`@` in `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers` means it takes the package `hardhat-network-helpers` with scope `@nomicfoundation` this is npm's package naming rule refer to https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/scope