# What does the at sign, or '@', mean as a prefix to an angular module as a package name?

Tags: angularjs, package

In my `package.json' file, it seems that all the Angular depedencies are prefixed by @. What does this mean? E.g.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
```

Why not just as below, with no @?

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of @ symbol in Node module names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

npm has two types of modules:

- Global modules - npm install mypackage
- [Scoped modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope) - npm install @myorg/mypackage

Scopes are a way of grouping related packages together, and also affect a few things about the way npm treats the package.