# Vue.js failing on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, npm, vue.js

I'm having trouble running my Vue.js application on a server. It works fine when I'm running locally on macOS or windows. This is the error I get when running 'npm run dev':

```
These dependencies were not found:

* @/components/account/Profile in ./src/router/index.js
* @/components/account/Plan in ./src/router/index.js
* @/components/account/Team in ./src/router/index.js
* @/components/account/Integration in ./src/router/index.js
* babel-runtime/helpers/extends in ./src/store/index.js
```

I have checked that the same version of Vue.js is installed  -> vue@2.5.13 + really have no clue how to fix this problem. I'm guessing it's a dependency/OS error because it runs with no errors locally.

Does anyone know to fix this or point me somewhere useful? Any help is hugely appreciated!

Edit***

Contents of Index.js below - I'm using Webpack.

```
import store from '../store'
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from '@/components/Home'
import Error404 from '@/components/404'
import Login from '@/components/Login'
import Register from '@/components/Register'
import FreeTrial from '@/components/FreeTrial'
import Product from '@/components/Product'
import Services from '@/components/Services'
import Team from '@/components/Team'
import Pricing from '@/components/Pricing'
import Help from '@/components/Help'
import SharedList from '@/components/SharedList'
import ListView from '@/components/App/ListView'
import Blog from '@/components/Blog'

// Account components, loaded lazily
const AccountSettings = r =>
  require.ensure([], () => r(require('@/components/AccountSettings')), 'accountComponents')

const ProfileSection = r =>
  require.ensure([], () => r(require('@/components/account/Profile')), 'accountComponents')

const PlanSection = r =>
  require.ensure([], () => r(require('@/components/account/Plan')), 'accountComponents')

const TeamSection = r =>
  require.ensure([], () => r(require('@/components/account/Team')), 'accountComponents')

const IntegrationSection = r =>
  require.ensure([], () => r(require('@/components/account/Integration')), 'accountComponents')

// App components loaded lazily, grouped by the 'appComponents' param
const MainApp = r =>
  require.ensure([], () => r(require('@/components/MainApp')), 'appComponents')
const Default = r =>
  require.ensure(
    [],
    () => r(require('@/components/App/Default')),
    'appComponents'
  )
const Search = r =>
  require.ensure(
    [],
    () => r(require('@/components/App/Search')),
    'appComponents'
  )
const Templates = r =>
  require.ensure(
    [],
    () => r(require('@/components/App/Templates')),
    'appComponents'
  )
const Lists = r =>
  require.ensure(
    [],
    () => r(require('@/components/App/Lists')),
    'appComponents'
  )
const Outreach = r =>
  require.ensure(
    [],
    () => r(require('@/components/App/Outreach')),
    'appComponents'
  )

import { Message } from 'element-ui'

Vue.use(Router)

export const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      name: '404',
      meta: { title: `Page not found` },
      component: Error404
    },
    {
      path: '/help',
      name: 'Help',
      meta: { title: `Help` },
      component: Help
    },
    {
      path: '/product',
      name: 'Product',
      meta: { title: `Product` },
      component: Product
    },
    {
      path: '/services',
      name: 'Services',
      meta: { title: `Services` },
      component: Services
    },
    {
      path: '/team',
      name: 'Team',
      component: Team
    },
    {
      path: '/pricing',
      name: 'Pricing',
      meta: { title: `Pricing` },
      component: Pricing
    },
    {
      path: '/blog',
      name: 'Blog',
      meta: { title: `Blog` },
      component: Blog
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      meta: { title: `Login` },
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'Register',
      meta: { title: `Register` },
      component: Register
    },
    {
      path: '/trial',
      name: 'FreeTrial',
      meta: { title: `Free trial` },
      component: FreeTrial
    },
    {
      path: '/viewlist/:id',
      name: 'SharedList',
      meta: { title: `View shared list` },
      component: SharedList
    },
    {
      path: '/app',
      component: MainApp,
      beforeEnter (from, to, next) {
        if (store.getters.getUserStatus.loggedIn) {
          next()
        } else {
          Message({
            message: `You can't access the app because you're not logged in`,
            type: 'error'
          })
          next({ name: 'Login' })
        }
      },
      children: [
        {
          path: '/account',
          component: AccountSettings,
          beforeEnter (from, to, next) {
            if (store.getters.getUserStatus.loggedIn) {
              next()
            } else {
              Message({
                message: `You can't access your profile because you're not logged in. Please log in again`,
                type: 'error'
              })
              next({ name: 'Login' })
            }
          },
          children: [
            {
              path: '',
              name: 'ProfileSection',
              meta: { title: `Edit profile` },
              component: ProfileSection
            },
            {
              path: 'plan',
              name: 'PlanSection',
              meta: { title: `Manage plan` },
              component: PlanSection
            },
            {
              path: 'team',
              name: 'TeamSection',
              meta: { title: `Manage team` },
              component: TeamSection
            },
            {
              path: 'integration',
              name: 'IntegrationSection',
              meta: { title: `Integration` },
              component: IntegrationSection
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          path: '',
          name: 'AppDefault',
          meta: { title: `Explore saphire` },
          component: Default
        },
        {
          path: 'search',
          name: 'AppSearch',
          meta: { title: `Search influencers` },
          component: Search
        },
        {
          path: 'templates',
          name: 'AppTemplates',
          meta: { title: `Manage templates` },
          component: Templates
        },
        {
          path: 'lists',
          name: 'AppLists',
          meta: { title: `Manage lists` },
          component: Lists
        },
        {
          path: 'list/:id',
          name: 'ListView',
          meta: { title: `View list` },
          component: ListView
        },
        {
          path: 'outreach',
          name: 'AppOutreach',
          meta: { title: `Outreach` },
          component: Outreach
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Change title based on meta.title property
  if (to.meta.title) {
    document.title = `saphire | ${to.meta.title}`
  } else {
    document.title = `saphire`
  }
  // Checking if inside or outside app and assigning the result to global store variable
  if (to.matched.length > 0) {
    to.matched[0].path === '/app'
      ? store.commit('setAppState', true)
      : store.commit('setAppState', false)
  }
  next()
})

export default router
```

Comment: Please add the content of `index.js` here as code, easier to debug then.
Oh, and add if your using Webpack or something like that as well. The paths are handled somewhat differently depending on the build packs.

Comment: @Anuga done - yes I'm using Webpack

Comment: Are you sure you're using the `@` symbol right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack

Comment: Can you do a `ls -aL` / `ll` / `dir` inside the `components` folder?
Seems to me, that either `account/` should be `account/` or that it's not a folder at all, seeing as `AccountSettings` isn't.