# What does '@' mean in those commands in npm?

Tags: npm, command

npm install jquery2@npm:jquery@2

```
npm install jquery3@npm:jquery@3

npm i case-1.5.3@npm:case@1.5.3

npm install -g @vue/cli

npm install -g @vue/cli-init

npm i my-express@https://github.com/expressjs/express/archive/4.16.3.tar.gz

npm i express@npm:@my-scope/express
```

I've just followed along, and have put those commands, without realizing what that '@' syntax actually means.

Now, I'm kinda confused whenever I come into  that '@' in every syntax.

Q : Does '@' mean the same in each syntax? and they're just some applications 
 with different usage?

Q : Why that '@' makes difference between

"npm install -g vue-cli" which installs Vue CLI 2

and

"npm install -g @vue/cli" which installs Vue CLI 3 ??

Q : why Vue CLI 3 installs with '/' ?? Is that command just defined by the distributor or mean something ??

To make the question clear,

I know each command's meaning in the first question, because I just memorized its those usage in whole.

But just don't know why that '@' makes difference in each usage.

Is that '@' just defined by the npm distributors to mean different in each usage?

or it just means the same in each command?

I think I missed something really important studying npm commands.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of the "at" (@) prefix on npm packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667258/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-at-prefix-on-npm-packages)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of @ symbol in Node module names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names)