# how to import a useful but unused file or folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I can't find any information on this case on the web, maybe someone would know how to do it.
I receive an warning message like `'FournisseursDb' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars` when I import this file.

[image]

It is not used but I need it to display my datas.

I saw on another project that the problem was being bypassed by this way (with a `@` before the folder):

[image]

And the import is replaced by:

[image]

I have tried but it doesn't work, when I change my import, I receive an error like `Module not found: Can't resolve '@fake-db' in '/Users/dev-delko/dev/delko/ledok-ui/src'` , I don't understand why. I have to add a library or something like this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe `// eslint-disable-next-line` that will help. More info here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line

Comment: Thanks @gugateider

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the `eslint` warning by adding the following line at the start of your file. But I still don't understand why do you need it if it's not getting used.

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
```

Comment: Thank you @ShivratnaKumar but what is the purpose of this @ in front of files and in imports ? this `FournisseursDb.js` file is a database simulation with mock from the `axios-mock-adapter` library. If I delete this import, I simply do not receive my datas.. The application needs it to work but does not use the file directly.

Comment: It's just a way to import scoped modules. You can read more about it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names