# Javascript import. What is the significance of “@“?

Tags: javascript, import

was wondering what is the significance of “@“ in the import.

For example: 
Import Container from “@core/material...”

Is it a pathing thing? Like ../ or ./?

Comment: Could indicate an npm “scope” https://docs.npmjs.com/about-scopes

Answer (score 0):

the @ will search through the `node_modules` rather than having to do something like `../../../../core/material`

so the @ points to the root of the project rather than the current directory.

This thread explains it further: [What does the @ symbol do in javascript imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711175/what-does-the-symbol-do-in-javascript-imports)

Comment: Not always. It could indicate a scoped package. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40186344/894067