# What's the difference between 'eslint' and '@eslint' in my node_modules?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, create-react-app, eslint

I made a fresh CRA app via `yarn create react-app` and installed `yarn add -D eslint`.
When selecting eslint path for my IDE, I noticed there's both `node_modules/eslint` and `node_modules/@eslint` in my project.
What's the difference and why are both there?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of @ symbol in Node module names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names)

Comment: @Nikasmusicandgaming Partly - now I know what it means, but still not sure why are both present and what's the difference between them.