# How to resolve Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'stimulus' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs

The browser console complains with:

```
Failed to register controller: test (controllers/test_controller) Error: Unable to resolve specifier 'stimulus'
```

[the highest line of source references points to where the error is triggere

```
if (!(name in registeredControllers)) {
    importShim(path, 'http://localhost:3000/assets/stimulus-loading-1fc59770fb1654500044afd3f5f6d7d00800e5be36746d55b94a2963a7a228aa.js')
      .then(module => registerController(name, module, application))
      .catch(error => console.error(`Failed to register controller: ${name} (${path})`, error))
  }
```

the last line points to the source of the problem:

```
// Eager load all controllers defined in the import map under controllers/**/*_controller
import { eagerLoadControllersFrom } from /*"@hotwired/stimulus-loading"*/'blob:http://localhost:3000/cf2bed28-84d1-496d-a453-7a2818e07002'
eagerLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

So clearly the `app/javascript/controllers/test-controller.js` is not firing properly.  Its first line calling

```
import { Controller } from "stimulus"
```

Which I find odd, as `app/javascript/controllers/application.js` contains the stock code

```
How does one resolve the specifier 'stimulus'?
import { Application } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const application = Application.start()

// Configure Stimulus development experience
application.debug = false
window.Stimulus   = application

export { application }
```

Comment: Stimulus is scoped under @hotwired https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293481/use-of-symbol-in-node-module-names I guess you can't call only "stimulus" in your controller

Comment: Well, the above test proves it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried this way? On app/javascript/controllers/test-controller.js write this way

**import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus";**

Comment: Yes, I stumbled upon this while back.  I was just circling back to this post to delete it, but it makes sense to keep it up if someone is comparing Rails 6 vs Rails 7.